# Regex to select third TD from every TR in HTML Table

Tags: html, regex

Here is the table example given below.
From the table, I want third column means third TD from every TR.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>One</td>
<td>Two</td>
<td>Three</td>
<td>Four</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Five</td>
<td>Six</td>
<td>Seven</td>
<td>Eight</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I tried

```
<td>(.*?)</td>
```

this matches every td.   Please tell me regex to select every third TD

Comment: (i) Do you want the third cell returned, deleted, replaced or else? (Your comment on Dibas Dayliya's answer suggests some replacement...) (ii) Is that an ordinary table - especially no `colspan`/`rowspan`? (And no attributes on `<tr>`/`<td>`?)

Comment: I want to remove third Td by find and replace

Comment: It is a simple html table with tbody, tr, td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you ONLY looking for `regex` solution?

I have some solution from `CSS` and `JavaScript`. Hopefully it helps you.

**From CSS**

```css
td:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

**From Javascript**

```js
const thirdTD = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-of-type(3)')
thirdTD.forEach(thirdTdEl => thirdTdEl.style.background = "green")
```

Comment: Thanks your CSS solution. I just added  display:none   to your CSS solution.

Comment: I wants it in find and replace

Comment: Are you satisfied with this answer?
Can you please explain your query in brief?